# create a new column based on cumulative occurrences of a specific value in another column pandas

Tags: pandas, cumulative-frequency

I want to count the number of occurrences of one specific value (string) in one column and write it down in another column cumulatively.

For example, counting the cumulative number of `Y` values here:

```
col_1  new_col
Y        1
Y        2
N        2
Y        3
N        3
```

I wrote this code but it gives me the final number instead of cumulative frequencies.

```
df['new_col'] = 0
df['new_col'] = df.loc[df.col_1 == 'Y'].count()
```

Comment: Why is N starting at 2?

Comment: I just want to count the number of "Y"s cumulatively.  So, "N" should not increase the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count both values cumulatively you can use:

```
df['new_col'] = (df
                 .groupby('col_1')
                 .cumcount().add(1)
                 .cummax()
                 )
```

If you want to focus on 'Y':

```
df['new_col'] = (df
                 .groupby('col_1')
                 .cumcount().add(1)
                 .where(df['col_1'].eq('Y'))
                 .ffill()
                 .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
                 )
```

Output:

```
  col_1  new_col
0     Y        1
1     Y        2
2     N        2
3     Y        3
4     N        3
```

Comment: Thanks. But how about a situation where the column does not start with "Y". What should I do there?

Comment: If the first value is not Y you can add `.fillna(0, downcast='infer')` as a last step of the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.assign(new_col=df1.col_1.eq("Y").cumsum())
```

Output:

```
  col_1  new_col
0     Y        1
1     Y        2
2     N        2
3     Y        3
4     N        3
```